# count all <br /> and replace number 4 with php

Tags: php, replace

i have text like

```
"Hello, Hello, how are you?
Hello, Hello, how are you?<br />
Hello,
Hello,<br />
How are you?
How are you today?
I am fine; I am great
I am fine;<br />
I am just great
I am fine; I am great
I'm very well today!<br />
Great!
Hello, Hello, how are you?<br />
Hello, Hello, how are you?
Hello, Hello, How are you?<br />
How are you today?"
```

i need to replace number fourth `<br />` to `<img>`

if only one `<br/>` found  , just replace the first

just one time

i try to use

```
function str_replace_first($from, $to, $subject)
{
    $from = '/'.preg_quote($from, '/').'/';

    return preg_replace($from, $to, $subject, 1);
}
```

but it's replace only number one found

i try to replace number 4

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your comment , ok i add it

Comment: You will probably need to use PHP REgeX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php

$txt  = "Hello, Hello, how are you?
Hello, Hello, how are you?<br />
Hello,
Hello,<br />
How are you?
How are you today?
I am fine; I am great
I am fine;<br />
I am just great
I am fine; I am great
I'm very well today!<br />
Great!
Hello, Hello, how are you?<br />
Hello, Hello, how are you?
Hello, Hello, How are you?<br />
How are you today?";

$occurrences = substr_count($txt, '<br />');
if( 1 === $occurrences ) {
    $txt = str_replace('<br />', "<img>", $txt);
} else {
    $counter = 1;
    $txt = preg_replace_callback("/<br \/>/", function ($m) use (&$counter) {

         // replace 4th occurance
         if ($counter++ == 4) {
              return "<img>";
         }

         return $m[0];

    }, $txt );
}

echo $txt;
```

Comment: i need to add some thing like that. $occurrences = substr_count($stwwr, '<br />');
$justit=ceil($occurrences/2)-1; to replace middle of it